# What is the correct term in sports for "get to the next round"?

Tags: single-word-requests, sports

What is the correct way to say that a team **got** to the next round? For example,

> "Team A won the quarter finals and **got** (the correct verb here) to semi-final"

Comment: There are probably good words to fill in the slot "The team (was) ____-ed to the next round." But your suggestion works great too: "The team got to the next round".

Comment: "The team advanced/qualified/moved/progressed/dashed to the next round

Comment: "advance" is the verb i hear used most often.  "clinch" is another one: "the team has clinched a spot in the semi-finals."

Comment: advanced .... "advanced to the semi-finals" 
(note "s" on finals because there are 2 semi-final rounds)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It [**qualified**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/qualify) for the semi-finals.

> 1.1 Become eligible for a competition or its final rounds, by reaching a certain standard or defeating a competitor: (Oxford)
>
> *England are in danger of failing to qualify*

Comment: (+1) As confirmation, **qualification games** can be mentioned. E.g. "The Asian section of the 2018 FIFA World Cup **qualification** acts as qualifiers for the 2018 FIFA World Cup, to be held in Russia, for national teams which are members of the Asian Football Confederation (AFC)". (Wikipedia)

Comment: In U.S. sports journalism, the usual formulation is "qualified" for the playoffs, but "advanced" to the next round/quarterfinals/semifinals/championship game (unless—as is often the case—each round has its own special formal or informal name such as "Division Series," "Conference Title," or "Sweet Sixteen," in which case the team winning at the previous level has "advanced" to that). The difference may reflect the fact that few U.S. sports have a qualifying round (as opposed to a regular season) in which multiple teams from a group advance to the knockout round (as happens in World Cup play).

Comment: @SvenYargs: Well put.

Comment: It might be worth considering here that you can *qualify* for something but never actually achieve it, e.g. a team might win the first round in a tournament and qualify to enter the next round, but choose to forfeit their position before ever entering the next round. In that sense, they never actually *got* to the next round.

Comment: @talrnu: Didn't think anyone would pick _that_ nit. Good one :)

Comment: @TusharRaj Indeed, a minor quibble resolved easily in context, but worth considering nonetheless.

Comment: +1. I'm upvoting this partly because it's a perfectly reasonable answer, but also because, as the 11th upvote for the accepted answer, it should qualify (or is that _advance_?) Tim Romano for a gold Populist badge. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Sven Yargs. Yipee :)

Answer (score 49):

Or the team *[advanced](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20team%20advanced%20to%20the%20next%20round&oq=the%20team%20advanced%20to%20the%20next%20round&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.4688j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)* to the next round.

Comment: This seems to be the phrase with the most common usages - however 'Progressed' also works and is common in the UK.

Answer (score 6):

In UK English, you'd often find the word "Progressed" used to describe moving onto the next stage of a contest

For example;

> Southampton ***progressed*** to the FA Cup fourth round after a narrow 1-0
>   win at Ipswich in their third-round replay at Portman Road.

http://www1.skysports.com/football/live/match/330266/report

Answer (score 4):

[And another is](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=moved%20to%20next%20round&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&prmd=ivns&ei=FTWEVaLqOY-eugSUtougBQ&start=10&sa=N)....

> [move into](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/move+into) - to come or go into;
>
> ≡come in, enter, get in, go in, go into, get into

- Andy Murray **moves into** second round at Queen's'. (3 days ago :)
- Roger Federer **moves** smoothly **into** fourth round ...

Comment: Potentially useful observation: I've seen *move **on** to* in this context more often in AmE than *move into*. Though I suppose "move on" is closer to the *advance/progress* answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally more inclined to use Tim Romano's suggestion of *advance*, but another term worth considering is *survive*, e.g. "The team *survived* the first round," or "The team *survived to* the final." This term emphasizes the struggle of the competition and might be considered more dramatic.